# MVC3 Web Grid adding action links at the begining of columns list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using MVC3 WebGrid control to render a list of entities. Assume I have an Index like page that renders a list of users, or items, orders etc. All these entties are having a column called ID.

The WebGrid looks well, the only thing I want is that once the list is rendered I want to add the 3 action links Edit, Delete, Detail prior to all other columns.

Adding the following code works but I don't want to repeat this code in all the pages:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(header: "",
                   style: "text-align-center",
                       format: (item) => new
                        HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID = item.ID     }).ToString() + " | " +
                                    Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { ID = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                                    Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { ID = item.ID }).ToString()
                                   )
            ),
            grid.Column("FirstName"),
            grid.Column("LastName"),
            grid.Column("EmailAddress")
        )
```

Basically what I want is to say @Grid.Render(Model) ... and it should create the first 3 action links and they render all the columns of the model.

I know that there are JQuery grids and MVCContrib etc but they are not the option please.

Any comments and tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom extension method for the grid:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class WebGridExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyGetHtml(this WebGrid grid, HtmlHelper html)
    {
        var columns =
            (from n in grid.ColumnNames
             select new WebGridColumn { ColumnName = n, CanSort = true }
             ).ToList<WebGridColumn>();
        columns.Insert(0, grid.Links(html));
        return grid.GetHtml(columns: columns, exclusions: new[] { "ID" });
    }

    public static WebGridColumn Links(this WebGrid grid, HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return grid.Column(
            header: "",
            style: "text-align-center",
            format: item => new HtmlString(
                html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { ID = item.ID }).ToString() + " | " +
                html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { ID = item.ID }).ToString()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@grid.MyGetHtml(Html)
```

or if you want to control the building of the other columns:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Links(Html),
        grid.Column("FirstName"),
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column("EmailAddress")
    )
)
```